# $\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)}\sin(x - y)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So I tried approaching from $x=0, y=0, y=x, y=x^2$, and $y=x^3$ and the resulting limits are all $0$ but apparently the limit doesn't exist. Why is this so?

Comment: Why makes you think the limit apparently does not exist?

Comment: It exists, and one can even use the word "obviously," since $x-y$ goes to $0$.

Comment: It was because my professor said so, and for this reason I couldn't understand why it was true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit exists and is zero. The easiest way to justify it is that $f(x,y) = \sin(x-y)$ is a compoisition of continuous functions and therefore is continuous itself. This means that $\lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x,y)= f(0,0) = 0$. I can even give you an epsilon-delta proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, and let $\delta = \epsilon/2$. I can show that if $||(x,y)|| < \delta$, then $|f(x,y)| < \epsilon$: $||(x,y)|| < \delta$ implies that $|x|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$. Then:

$$|f(x,y)| = |\sin(x-y)| \le |x-y| \le |x|+|y| < \delta+\delta = 2\delta = \epsilon
$$

If your professor said that the limit doesn't exist, then unless the question wasn't stated correctly, I'm sad to say that he/she is wrong.